# Show keyboard shortcut command

Tags: 16.04, command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I want to see which command gets executed when pressing a keyboard shortcut.

My use case: I have an external keyboard with no volume up/down keys (also no Fn + ...). The keyboard on my laptop has these keys. I want to define a custom shortcut for my external keyboard to execute the same command as the Volume control keys on my laptop-keyboard.

I found a lot of answers on how to create a custom shortcut but I could not find a way to see which commands gets executed when using an existing shortcut.

Comment: There often is no command being executed by a GUI action. For specific cases, there might be equivalent commands, like in the second duplicate for setting volume.

Comment: Thanks, I already saw the answers of the "Terminal command ..." link but that did not have to same effects as using the keys, for example the sliders in the sound settings are note adjusted accordingly